# PostgreSQL Password authentification fails

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, psql

I cannot login to psql using password and I actually don't understand at all how authentification is working in postgresql.

If I do the following command i expect to be asked for re_managers password and if my entered password matches I expect to log in successfully.

```
ubuntu@server:~/workspace $ psql -U re_manager -d testdb -W
```

but it fails no matter what with this error

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "re_manager"
```

if I change user to re_manager and then do this then it log in with no errors:

```
re_manager@server:/home/ubuntu/workspace$ psql -d testdb
```

Now it gets really strange: if I force psql to ask for password using:

```
re_manager@server:/home/ubuntu/workspace$ psql -d testdb -W
```

Then it ask me for a password but accepts any password.

Would be great to have some explanation.

Thanks for help

Amit

Comment: Apparently your Postgres is not configured for password authentication, but for "peer" authentication.

Comment: Please read this official doc on [postgresql auth-methods](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/auth-methods.html). Basically peer-auth allows the mapping between system and database user names..

Comment: Read the PostgreSQL documentation, particularly the chapter about client authentication and the `pg_hba.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how peer authentication works. Said when you have SystemUser=a and DatabaseUser=a when you login to that SystemUser you have Access to All Database and Table Created by the DatabaseUser. For more info [Authentication Methode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-methods.html) and how to change the Authentication Methode on [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)